# What requirements are there for a valid US postcard?

Tags: print-design, reference-request

When designing postcards meant to be sent with the US Postal Service, what requirements to we need to keep in mind when working on the design?

Which areas are we free to use for designs, and which areas need to be left blank or filled in with specific details, in order for the postal service to be able to process and manage?

And second, what sizes of postcard are acceptable in US mail?

Comment: I found the answer to the second question, if someone wants to incorporate the information into their answer: http://web.archive.org/web/20080120115502/http://www.usps.com/businessmail101/mailcharacteristics/cards.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can check with your printer or online printer for guidelines/templates depending on the size postcard you are designing for Direct Mail. Any post office will tell you if your PC will work if you take a sample to them. For a 4x6 PC with a mailing panel you can see the attached for reference. I have done thousands of DM pieces and have always stuck with these general measurements for a starting point.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, maybe [this](http://designerstoolbox.com/designresources/postcards/).